# Передача активити в статический метод

Tags: android, kotlin

Я хочу создать синглтон в котором будут методы для оценки приложения в google play. Для таких метод мне нужен контекст, а для их новой библиотеки для отзывов и вовсе активити. Подскажите плиз, если я передам в свой синглтон activity для контекста, через параметр метода, и использовать его буду только там. Это будет вызывать утечку памяти или ещё что-то плохое?

```
object RateAppManager{

    fun googlePlayInAppReview(activity: Activity?, reviewManager: ReviewManager) {
        val requestFlow = reviewManager.requestReviewFlow()
        requestFlow.addOnCompleteListener { request ->
            if (request.isSuccessful) {
                val reviewInfo = request.result
                val flow = activity?.let { reviewManager.launchReviewFlow(it, reviewInfo) }
                flow?.addOnCompleteListener { _ ->
                }
            } else {
                activity?.let { showRateAppDialog(it) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: это очень плохая затея, я не работал с данной библиотекой, поэтому не могли бы вы пожалуйста объяснить зачем вам активность нужна? и почему нельзя вызывать это в активности?

Comment: Утечки не должно быть. В принципе использовать можно, если нет другого выхода

Comment: @Andrew а почему плохая затея? Расскажите пожалуйста подробнее. Быблиотека требует активность а не просто контекст. Вот я ее и передаю. А вынес в синглтон так как у меня несколько методов для оценки приложения и я хочу их держать в одном месте с возможностью вызова с разных мест.

Comment: вам уже дали ответ в котором более-менее все описано, я бы предложил использовать это напрямую в активностях, но можно попробовать вынести наружу все что вам нужно конечно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сама по-себе передача контекста в метод для использования его там же - нормальная практика.
Так как параметр метода это локальная переменная и она уничтожается по выходу из него, то ничего страшного в этом нет, **но** только в том случае, когда эта переменная не копируется (передаётся) за пределы метода.
В данном случае это не так: ссылка передаётся в анонимную реализацию слушателя и время её жизни теперь зависит от времени жизни этого объекта.
Я не знаю ни эту библиотеку, ни как вы её используете - поэтому не могу сказать будет у вас утечка или нет.
Утечка гарантирована если слушатель продолжит работать после выхода из активности, ссылку на которую он хранит.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @МаксимШимко если вам дан иссчерпыюващий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.